# How to send unsigned bytes through serial from arduino

Tags: arduino, uart

I am using the sketch below to send the bytes of the frame buffer display.screen of 1536 bytes in size, to the computer over serial communication. The result of it to my java program is a byte array with values between 127 and -128. The result I am seeking of in java program is a byte array with values between 0 and 1. How could I declare the value of i to be an unsigned byte?

```
#include <TVout.h>
#include <video_gen.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define BAUD (9600)
#define W 128
#define H 96
#define compute ((TV.hres()/8) * TV.vres())

TVout TV;

SoftwareSerial Sserial(0, 1);

void setup() {
  Sserial.begin(BAUD);  
  delay(1000);
  TV.begin(PAL, W, H);
  initOverlay();
  initInputProcessing();
}  

void initOverlay() {
  TCCR1A = 0;
  TCCR1B = _BV(CS10);  
  TIMSK1 |= _BV(ICIE1);
  EIMSK = _BV(INT0);
  EICRA = _BV(ISC11);
}

void initInputProcessing() {
  ADCSRA &= ~_BV(ADEN); 
  ADCSRB |= _BV(ACME); 
  ADMUX &= ~_BV(MUX0); 
  ADMUX |= _BV(MUX1);
  ADMUX &= ~_BV(MUX2);
  ACSR &= ~_BV(ACIE);  
  ACSR &= ~_BV(ACIC); 
}

ISR(INT0_vect) {
  display.scanLine = 0;
}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  TV.capture();
  for (int i=0; i<compute; i++)
    {
      Sserial.write(display.screen[i]);
    }
  delay(3000);
}
```

Comment: There are no unsigned bytes in Java. Since you want to have values between 0 and 1, maybe what you really want is an array of `float` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to the receiving program to interpret the data as an 8-bit fraction.

On the wire, the data is just eight bits; there is no inherent signed-ness or implied binary-point (or any other interpretation).  Your java program will have to interpret the byte as an unsigned fraction, if that's what you need, something like [pseudo-code]: `frac = (float)(unsigned)b/256.;`.